# Find Participants - pulling up too many names not related to the class

Tags: civievent

Find Participants - pulling up the names but when you hit one of the buttons above name to put them in alpha order it pulls up everyone that has taken a class.

I hit FIND PARTICIPANTS

I add pull down the menu to find the specific

Comment: Hi Deb - can you pls try replicating at https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/. I did the following
- Find Participants - Search - shows 50 (all people who have done an event)
- repeat but set for Event = Rain-forest cup - shows 18, click on Participants to reorder, still see 18

Comment: if you can replicate pls add some screenshots to help document the issue

Comment: if you cannot replicate then mention what version you are on, and perhaps do an upgrade to latest in case it was a bug that has been fixed

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on very old version of CiviCRM, Similar [issue](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/981) was reported 10 months ago and was fixed in [5.14.1](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/14322/files)

You can either upgrade CiviCRM to latest or apply [patch](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/14322.patch)